# play with friends using facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to add an option play with friends in my game. I am currently using photon unity networking which doesn't support that feature. The only workaround will be that all the players should know the room information so that they can join the same room. For that purpose, I am thinking of using Facebook invite system. I can send the invite to players who are currently using my game. Is there some way by which I can receive the invite within the app/game ? Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

There is facebook sdk for Unity3d, so you can just integrate it whatever you want about facebook, add friend, request friend list, invite friend etc..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the task a lot more easy (and invest a few bucks), you should check out prime[31] and the plugins they offer.
https://prime31.com/plugins